Closed formula for sum of rounded up power of two fractions of a positive whole number
Given $n\in\mathbb{N}_{\gt 0}$ provide a closed formula for
$$
f(n):=\sum_{l=0}^{\lceil\log_2(n)\rceil} \bigg\lceil\frac{n}{2^l}\bigg\rceil
$$
If there is $k\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $n=2^k$, we have
$$
f(n)=\sum_{l=0}^{k} 2^{k-l}=2^{k+1}-1
$$
obviously, but what about other numbers?
Another easy observation is:
$$
f(2n+2) = 1 + f(2n+1)\quad{}(n\in\mathbb{N}_{\gt 0})
$$
but I was not able to use that, to provide a closed formula.
This is not homework, it us just an itch I could not scratch for
now. If there was a formula for that sum, I could calculate some memory requirement for a function I am implementing more precisely. At the moment, I just overestimate it using $f(n) \le f(2^k)$ if $n \le 2^k$.

I don't think you can get a closed form formula for this, but a better approximation is $2n \le f(n) \le 2n + \lceil \log_2 n \rceil + 1$

Thanks for the nice upper bound. For the lower bound you have a typo, it should be $2n-1$.
